# PHP PDO prepare and execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

Unfortunately I dont see the problem:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE work 
            SET status = :status, date_from = :dateFrom
            WHERE id = :id
            ";
    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
        ':status' => $status,
        ':date_from' => $dateFrom,
        ':id' => $id
    ));
```

Comment: What are the values of the variables, are any of them null?  For example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5dd0cd847c2d5fb71d0f3aefa74e6681f9bbe93d

Comment: `date_from = :dateFrom` should be `date_from = :date_from`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a spelling error

```
:dateFrom !== :date_from
```

So change code to

```
$sql = "UPDATE work 
            SET status = :status, date_from = :dateFrom
            WHERE id = :id
            ";
    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
        ':status' => $status,
        ':dateFrom' => $dateFrom,
        ':id' => $id
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The prepared method will generate a precompiled query with no values, the execute method will generate an array of values associated to each empty parameter, the rest happens at a level lower than SQL, where the query is precompiled, and values are fetched only afterwards to avoid the so famous SQL injection.
Just sharing this so you kind of follow what is actualy happening.